# How coockies could be used to get user data?

Tags: php, cookies, network-programming, session-cookies

I heard that people may use cookies for hacking activities.

As browsing information being stored in cookies, one can think that it's dangerous to share your cookies.

When I visited one of the web site it prompted this message:

[image: Message on web page]

1. How can they access user's cookies in his system?
2. What can they do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are data stored by any website you've visited on your browser cache. 
It can store **anything**, including data you gave to this site (email, card number, phone, name...)

For example, google & amazon use cookie to let you connected for several days... It stores your login (but it do not store your password)
It really depends on how the website is designed for.

Only original website which putted data in this particular cookie can read this data.

Actually, I think the only way for hackers to get stored cookies data is to **hack original website** : thanks to that, it will be allowed to read data.

You can **read yourself** data stored in cookie by browsing your cookie directory (depends on which browser you are using). 
For example, in firefox, you can see it in options > private > delete specific cookies